# Naming a Cell in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a series of macros to audit some financial models. 
The first macro I’m trying to create is one that names the current cell.  Why? I want to name the cell, after that I’m going to record a macro to click the “Trace Precedents” and go to the cell that has the relationship.

After that I need to go back to the original cell, thats the named one. That's easy on the go function, but I need to the naming macro working

My recorded code for the naming macro is as follows:

```
Sub Namer ()

    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Name1", RefersToR1C1:="=Workings!R42C6"
    ActiveWorkbook.Names("Name1").Comment = ""

End Sub
```

I have the following problems:

1. I need to name the current cell on a workbook with a lot of sheets. I’m gonna be moving between sheets but my recorded code has a “fixed” sheet. 
   How can I fix that? Name the current cell on the current sheet

Comment: You may find [this](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-ways-to-reference-excel-workbooks-and-sheets-using-vba/) to be useful

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help you ...

```
Public Sub CreatesNames()
    Dim objSheet As Worksheet

    For Each objSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        objSheet.Names.Add Name:="Name1", RefersTo:=objSheet.Range("A1")
    Next
End Sub
```

... something to note, names can be created at the worksheet level or at the workbook level, so, if you're going to be creating the same name across worksheets then you need to use a `Worksheet` object, not the `Workbook` object.

So to use the active cell ...

**Sheet Level**

```
ActiveSheet.Names.Add Name:="Name1", RefersTo:=ActiveCell
```

**Workbook Level**

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Name1", RefersTo:=ActiveCell
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: The problem with that: It names all the A1 on the Workbook, but I need a way to name the active cell only.